# Node.js - Is there any front-end js? Or is it all backend?

Tags: javascript, node-js

With Node.JS as a backend solution; is there any frontend javascript or all events controlled on the backend?

Answer (score 5):

It is completely separate from client-side JS. Like any other browser/server scenario you still have that http middle-man/wall to throw things over. There are plenty of advantages to having both be the same language like sharing core utility libraries, of course, but it will still take an Ajax call to make a mouse event matter to the server.

Answer (score 3):

As with any web server, Node is compatible with client Javascript requests - the [base repository](https://github.com/joyent/node) does not include any front-end Javascript, however, demos like [Node Chat](https://github.com/ry/node_chat) include front-end scripts (i.e. jQuery).